# UITextView Font Adjustment

Tags: swift, textview

I'm trying to implement the same behavior as the original Notes app does. In the screen where we start typing the note out, the heavy font is designed for the headline, when we press on space button, it goes forward to the next line, the font is also changed to smaller one for the main text. Is there any way to implement font adjustment within one textview?

Here is my code snippet:

```
extension InsertViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let currentText = textView.text ?? ""
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 50, weight: .heavy)]
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: currentText, attributes: attributes)
    textView.attributedText = attributedString
    if textView.text.last?.isNewline == true {
        print("new line")
        let newLine = textView.text ?? ""
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)]
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: newLine, attributes: attributes)
        textView.attributedText = attributedString
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample snippet codes.

Comment: I'm trying to compare the last character to the space before moving forward to the next line, and it changes the entire text font. I need to find a way to observe the text I've just typed in, keep it original font, and then change the font of the next line.

Comment: extension InsertViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text.last == "\n" {
            textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)
        }
    }

Comment: @AudwinOyong, just point me to how it can be worked out. Thank you in advance!